# Finite Commutative Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a finite commutative group. prove that G is not cyclic if and only if G has a subgroup that is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{p}\times \mathbb Z_{p}$ for some prime number p.

Can you give me a hint? I even don't know how to start.

Comment: there is no information about the order of G. It is just finite.

Comment: OP, do you have at your disposal any classification-type theorems for finite abelian groups, or perhaps sufficient conditions for a group being cyclic (such as having at most $n$ solutions to $x^n=1$ for each divisor $n\mid\#G$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two directions to consider. To prove that if $G$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ for some prime $p$, then $G$ is not cyclic, ponder the following facts:

1) Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

2) The group $\mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_p$ is not cyclic.

To prove that if $G$ is not cyclic then it contains a subgroup of the form $\mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_p$ for some prime $p$, ponder the following:

1) The fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

2) If $gcd(m,n)=1$, then $\mathbb Z_n\times \mathbb Z_m\cong \mathbb Z_{n\cdot m}$.

Use 2) to eliminate factors in the presentation of $G$ as a product of cyclic groups. Use the fact that $G$ is not cyclic to find two factors along the way with non-trivial common divisor. Take a prime divisor of that common divisor. Conclude the desired result.